# Why am I getting an error message when trying to check download authenticity?

Tags: linux, debian

**What needs to be done to check the authenticity/ validity of the debian 10 download?**
This is for a single arm board computer. The following information is from armbian. So far, I have only inputted the 1st gpg command, so the output is only for the first gpg command.

```
# download public key from the database: 
gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key DF00FAF1C577104B50BF1D0093D6889F9F0E78D5
gpg --verify Armbian_5.18_Armada_Debian_jessie_3.10.94.img.asc
```

1... Getting the following error message:

```
UBUNTU: (gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key DF00FAF1C577104B50BF1D0093D6889F9F0E78D5
gpg: key 93D6889F9F0E78D5: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 93D6889F9F0E78D5: "x@armbian.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1)
```

https://docs.armbian.com/User-Guide_Getting-Started/#how-to-check-download-authenticity

Answer (score 0):

If you add a 0x it [seems to work on the website](http://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?search=0xDF00FAF1C577104B50BF1D0093D6889F9F0E78D5&fingerprint=on&op=index).

The command does work on my end.

```
gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xDF00FAF1C577104B50BF1D0093D6889F9F0E78D5
gpg: key 93D6889F9F0E78D5: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 93D6889F9F0E78D5: "Igor Pecovnik <igor@armbian.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

If you look at the [details](http://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=vindex&fingerprint=on&search=0x93D6889F9F0E78D5) there are cross singings available which the other missing keys might be refering to.

Check also [How to display gpg key details without importing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136029/how-to-display-gpg-key-details-without-importing-it).